# Problems getting my bibliography working - "empty bibliography!

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors

This has been stressing me out for a couple of hours now. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 with Texmaker as the editor. I've been trying to use a `.bib` file as an external bibliography, which I've typed up in a text document. Every guide I've seen has said that I've needed to "run" `bibtex`, and they talk as if `bibtex` is a program, but I can't for the life of me find `bibtex` as a piece of software anywhere on the internet.

Here are the important parts of my main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{float}

\bibliography{biblio}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

Document text here.

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

And here is my bibliography: http://www.filedropper.com/biblio

It gives me a fair few warnings.

```
1: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing. 
1: 'Data encoding is 'utf8'
131: 'Citation 'EPS' on page 6 undefined (defined in the .bib file
134: 'Empty bibliography' This is the big one. Bibliography clearly not empty!
1: 'There were undefined references'
1: 'Please (re)run BibTeX on one file(s): (biblatex)diss (biblatex) and rerun latex afterwards'
```

I don't understand how I can "run" `biblatex`? Isn't `biblatex` the language?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, BibTeX is a processor/program/application, just like (La)TeX. You specify `backend=bibtex` in your [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) loading option. You need to run it - `bibtex` - on your file in order to have a bibliography.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5764)

Comment: Welcome! `bibtex` is a programme just like `pdflatex` or `latex` or `xelatex` (or whatever you use to compile). If you compile at the command line, you just say `bibtex <filename>` or `bibtex <filename>.aux`. If you use an editor, usually it has a button or menu option to run BibTeX.

Comment: Thank you cfr. This was it. I didn't realise that "bibtex" was a compile option. Cheers!

Comment: Would you be OK with closing your question as a duplicate of [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5764) then?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate. I just couldn't find anywhere online that clearly described BibTex as a compiling option. But yes I believe this can be closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not cited any document, that's the reason for message "bibliography empty".  I added one `\cite` command.  See the commented `\nocite{*}` in the mwe. You can use it to test the bib file (it shows all bib entries in the bibliography).

To get rid of the other errors/warnings you mentioned I changed your code a little bit (see the markings `<===========`).

Copy the following MWE, name it `mwe.tex` and compile it first with `pdflatex mwe.tex`.  Then you will get an file `mwe.aux` needed for the next step.  Use now `bibtex mwe` to create the bibliography with BiBTeX, afterwards  `pdflatex mwe.tex` two times.

Because you use encoding utf-8 it would be better to use `biber` instead of `bibtex`.  Then change line `backend=bibtex` to `backend=biber` and use `biber mwe` instead `bibtex mwe` to create the bibliography.

MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have `bib` file and `tex` code in one mwe):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{CS,
  Title                    = {Chemistry in Space. From Interstellar Matter to Organic Life},
  Author                   = {Dieter Rehder},
  Publisher                = {John Wiley and Sons},
  Year                     = {2010},
  ISBN                     = {9783527326891},
  Keywords                 = {physics}
}

@Article{EPS,
  Title                    = {Energy Production in Stars},
  Author                   = {Hans Albrecht Bethe},
  Journal                  = {Physical Review},
  Year                     = {1939},
  Number                   = {5},
  Pages                    = {434--456},
  Volume                   = {55},
  DOI                      = {http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.55.434},
  Keywords                 = {physics}
}

@Book{FP,
  Title                    = {Fusion Physics},
  Author                   = {Mitsuru Kikuchi and Karl Lackner and Minh Quang Tran},
  Publisher                = {International Atomic Energy Agency},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Series                   = {International Atomic Energy Agency},
  ISBN                     = {9789201304100},
  Keywords                 = {physics}
}

@Book{INP,
  Title                    = {Introductory Nuclear Physics},
  Author                   = {Kenneth S. Krane},
  Publisher                = {John Wiley and Sons},
  Year                     = {1987},
  ISBN                     = {9780471805533},
  Keywords                 = {physics}
}

@Book{PIF,
  Title                    = {The Physics of Inertial Fusion},
  Author                   = {Stefano Atzeni},
  Publisher                = {Oxford University Press},
  Year                     = {2009},
  Series                   = {International Series of Monographs on Physics},
  ISBN                     = {9780199568017},
  Keywords                 = {physics}
}

@Article{SES,
  Title                    = {Synthesis of the Elements in Stars},
  Author                   = {K. MARGARET BURBIDGE and G. R. BURBIDGE and WILLIAM A. FOWLER and F. HOYLE},
  Journal                  = {Reviews of Modern Physics},
  Year                     = {1957},
  Number                   = {4},
  Pages                    = {547--650},
  Volume                   = {29},
  DOI                      = {http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.29.547},
  Keywords                 = {physics}
}

@Article{SEWMS,
  Title                    = {Stellar Evolution Within and off the Main Sequence},
  Author                   = {Icko Iben},
  Journal                  = {Annual Review of Astronomy and Astrophysics},
  Year                     = {1966},
  Pages                    = {571--626},
  Volume                   = {5},
  DOI                      = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1967ARA%26A...5..571I},
  Keywords                 = {physics}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes} % <==================================
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex, % biber bibtex % <=======================
  style=alphabetic,
  sorting=ynt,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{float}

%\bibliography{biblio} % <===============not needed =======
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Document text here. \cite{CS} % <==========================
%\nocite{*} %                   <==========================
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

BTW: `biblatex` is a package to make layouting bibliographys a little bit easier. It works very good with Biber, that knows to use utf-8 encoding.  Today you should use `biblatex` with Biber.

PS: I deleted the code for your `@preamble`, because it seems not to be needed here.  Where does it come from?  Are you sure you really need it?